# ViewController with Skview - SpriteKit SKScene

Tags: uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skview

first try and bit stuck on this one...

I Have a ViewController that I wish to display an SKScene in its view
I've tried everything I can think of but its not showing

---

- add SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h
- Main.storyboard has a single view controller (myViewController).
- myViewController's view - change class to be SKView. (see pic below)
- Viewdidload
- link to SKScene I wish to load (HelloScene) #import "HelloScene.h"

---

```
//ViewController.m
#import "myViewController.h"
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "HelloScene.h"
@interface myViewController ()

@end

@implementation myViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
    spriteView.showsDrawCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

---

HelloScene.h

```
 #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
  @interface HelloScene : SKScene 
  @end
```

---

HelloScene.m

```
#import "HelloScene.h"

@interface HelloScene ()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@end

@implementation HelloScene

- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) view
{
        [self LoadSceneContents];
}

- (void)LoadSceneContents
{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    [self addChild: [self newHelloNode]];
}

- (SKLabelNode *)newHelloNode
{
    SKLabelNode *helloNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    helloNode.text = @"Hello, World!";
    helloNode.fontSize = 42;
    helloNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    return helloNode;
}

@end
```

---

[image]

Above:Selecting the view controller’s view object and change its class to SKView

Answer (score 1):

Had missed to configure the scene properly...

```
// Create and configure the scene.
    HelloScene *theScene = [HelloScene sceneWithSize:spriteView.bounds.size];
    theScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [spriteView presentScene:theScene

];
```

Hope it helps somebody else